# win 7 batch file to open excel file with highest number starting

Tags: batch-file, windows-7-x64

I need a bit of help...
I have a batch file to open up the highest number (number at start of filename) of excel file, just so I can use a shortcut instead of having to browse the folder every single time and open the highest number file manually...

As I am sure it is obvious to many of you that my code counts back from 55 to 1 and when the first file name is found to be existing then it would open it up and terminate the batch file.

Now, it succeeds at counting back and recognizing the first existing file so I thought the wildcards were right, but it fails at opening up the file so my wildcards are not right in some way for that...

My filename starts are over the "10" two digit mark so I didn't care about taking care of %%I for the FOR cycles before %%I=10... it doesn't matter...

[image: File names in the Folder together with the script]

So here it is:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
SET count=55
SET break=
FOR /L %%I IN (%count%,-1,1) DO (IF NOT DEFINED break (CALL :routine %%I) ELSE  (GOTO :end))

:routine
IF EXIST %1*.xlsx "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "%1*.xlsx" & SET break=yes

:end
```

What the file name in parameter is recognized as is this:

```
11*.XLSX
```

Instead of this:

```
11-AD-13-03-2017.xlsx
```

Thanks a lot to all of you reading...
It is very much appreciated...
Andras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
for /F %%a in ('dir /B *-AD-*.xlsx ^| sort /R') do (
    set FILENAME=%%a
    goto :OPENFILE )

:OPENFILE
start excel %FILENAME%
```

This uses the `sort` command to sort the files so the highest number is on top.

Comment: `dir /O:-N` command show the files in reversed order, so the `sort /R` command is not needed...

Comment: Bravo... Thanks again for both you and LotPings... It is very much appreciated...

Comment: This was my first request on this website.... I have not used it before this time. This is a great website...

Answer (score 3):

Since the number has a fixed length you simply need to sort reverse on names.
The first entry has the highest number.

```
@Echo off
Set "Highest="
for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/O-N ??-AD-*.xlsx'
) Do If not defined Highest (Set "Highest=%%A"&Set "FileName=%%A-%%B")
Echo Highest number is : %Highest% file name: %Filename%
```

Output with your sample data:

```
Highest number is : 11 file name: 11-AD-13-03-2017.xlsx
```

---

**EDIT**
If the files reside on a ntfs formatted drive (with inherent sort on name) this is all you need:

```
for %%A in (??-AD-*.xlsx) Do set FileName=%%A
```

Comment: Thank you very much for both you and abelenky... Two of you came up with just as functional and elegant solution... abelenky's one I don't need to modify to work as I wanted it to work...